# Running IE browser instance via WatiN on Azure

Tags: azure, watin, unauthorized

I'm attempting to run some browser automation tasks in an Azure WebRole, but am encountering the following error when trying to instantiate the IE browser instance:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

The code runs fine in the Azure emulator.

I've done a little reading and come to the conclusion that I probably need to use the DCOMCNFG utility to modify permissions to allow the IIS user to launch an IE instance, but the AppID that the CLSID above references isn't listed in the DCOMCNFG utility anywhere so I can't change these permissions.

Does anybody have any ideas? I'm about at my wit's end.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code elevated by modifying your `.csdef` file with adding the following inside each `*Role` element (`WebRole`/`WorkerRole`):

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

This will run your code as Local System account.

Comment: Did not work in my case... Interesting information anyways, thank you.

Comment: what does it mean "did not work" - did you troubleshoot the issue? Execution context elevated will run your task under Local System Account - this is the most privileged account that can exists on a Windows system. If something fails, it may be due to the fact that this account has no user profile. Which is also work-aroundable.